# Execute Openmp program in LLVM-3.0

Tags: llvm, openmp, llvm-gcc, llvm-3.0

I generated a .ll file using llvm-gcc for a Openmp program(written in c).
Then Optimized using opt(version 3.0)
But when I try to execute the optimized .ll file using lli or llvm-ld, getting the following errors,

```
        LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'GOMP_parallel_start' which could not be resolved!
```

Here is the step I followed,

```
   $ llvm-gcc -emit-llvm loop11.c -fopenmp -o loop.ll -S
   $ opt -O3  loop.ll -o loop.opt.ll -S
   $ lli loop.opt.ll
    LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'GOMP_parallel_start' which could not be resolved!
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to link / load the OpenMP runtime, libgomp in this case.

Comment: I tried linking OpenMP runtime libgomp,                          [[$llvm-ld -l="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgomp.a" op.bc]]                                         getting same error.

Comment: This will work only if you're using llvm-ld to generate the native code. You will either compile libgomp into LLVM IR and link it in, or *load* libgomp.so into lli's process. Also, make sure that LLVM was compiled with libffi support.